# the warning labels that must show up when the input format is false doesn't work

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, nuxt.js

```
    <template>
  <form class="form">
    <h1 class="form__title">Personal Info</h1>
    <p class="form__subtitle">
      Please provide your name, email address, and phone number
    </p>
    <div class="form__content">
      <div class="form__input" v-for="info in formInfo" :key="info.label">
        <div class="form__input__labels">
          <label :for="info.name" class="form__input__labels__name">{{
            info.label
          }}</label>
          <!-- <label
            class="form__input__labels__req"
            v-if="info.required && !info.inputValue"
            >this field is required</label> -->
          <label
            class="form__input__labels__req"
            :for="info.name"
            v-if="!info.isInputValid"
            >invalid {{ info.name }}</label
          >
        </div>
        <input
          :type="info.type"
          :name="info.name"
          class="form__input__item"
          :placeholder="info.placeholder"
          v-model="info.inputValue"
          @change="validateUserInpt(info.inputValue, info.type)"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="form__btn">Next Step</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const userInput = ref<string>("");
const userEmail = ref<string>("");
const userPhoneInput = ref<number | null>(null);

interface FormInfo {
  label: string;
  type: string;
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  inputValue: string | number | null;
  required: boolean;
  isInputValid: boolean;
}

const formInfo = ref<FormInfo[]>([
  {
    label: "Name",
    type: "text",
    name: "name",
    placeholder: "e.g. Stephen King",
    inputValue: userInput.value,
    required: true,
    isInputValid: false,
  },
  {
    label: "Email Address",
    type: "email",
    name: "email",
    placeholder: "e.g. stephenking@lorem.com",
    inputValue: userEmail.value,
    required: true,
    isInputValid: false,
  },
  {
    label: "Phone Number",
    type: "number",
    name: "phone",
    placeholder: "e.g, +1 234 567 890",
    inputValue: userPhoneInput.value,
    required: true,
    isInputValid: false,
  },
]);

const validateUserInpt = (value: any, type: string) => {
  const nameRegex: RegExp = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/; // regex for letters and spaces only
  const emailRegex: RegExp = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/; // regex for valid email format
  const phoneRegex: RegExp = /^\+?\d{1,3}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$/; // regex for valid phone format
  formInfo.value.forEach((info) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "name":
        info.isInputValid = nameRegex.test(value);
        break;
      case "email":
        info.isInputValid = emailRegex.test(value);
        break;
      case "phone":
        info.isInputValid = phoneRegex.test(value);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
};
</script>
```

I want the "invalid name" , "invalid email", and "invalid phone" to show up when the user types sth in an incorrect format but nothing shows up and looks like it is not reactive, when i change the initial value of isInputValid to false, the label shows up but it doesn't go away when the user types.I assign the value of regex.test to isInputValid and then if the regex.test returns false, the label would show up.